# Unselectable text - Cross browser solution

Tags: css, cross-browser

Is there any equivalent for `-moz-user-select` / `-webkit-user-select` for IE6 ?

I would like the text on my page not to be selectable in all major browsers.

What is the best solution for that ?

Comment: check here [**unselectable text in ie**](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1184318&page=1)

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this?!? Is this some kind of protection for your content (like the infamous 'disable right click' scripts)? I think it only annoys the users... (especially people with weird habits, like selecting the text that they are reading)

Comment: First thing it will annoy your users and if you want to protect the content then don't put it on internet, because if it is really important and people need it there will me many ways for them to get rid of any protection, just a simple google search will fetch them number of ways for that.

Comment: STOP SUPPORTING IE6

Comment: -1 for IE6 + Annoying browser behavior.

Comment: Say you created a CSS styled button.  You'd want to disable the text on that button.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: Can be usefull for ui elements, ie ExtJs uses this

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Unselectable text</title>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;">

<style>
  .column {width: 30em; margin: 1em;}
  p {position: relative; z-index: 1; //height: 100%;} /* you can remove //height if declare doctype */ 
  .unselector {display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0;}
  .unselector img {display: block; position: absolute; z-index: 3; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
</style>

  <div class="column">
    <p>
    <span class="unselector"><img src="1.gif" alt="" border="0" /></span>
    Activists on&nbsp;ships raided by&nbsp;Israeli commandos cast doubt on&nbsp;Israel's version of&nbsp;events that led&nbsp;to at&nbsp;least nine deaths. Yes, the webpage is currently not available. 
    </p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

p.s. 1.gif is transparent 1px*1px image

Comment: why use an img if you can "not use" an img?

Answer (score 0):

if this is for a small element masking, i will go with have an empty DIV over the text, and giving the DIV an absolute position with z-index higher than the text's. make sure the DIV is coving everything.