# HTML How can I prevent someone highlighting text within divs?

Tags: javascript, html

Firstly yes I have found this link:

[Is there a way to make text unselectable on an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430/is-there-a-way-to-make-text-unselectable-on-an-html-page)

but it doesn't seem to work for me. I have lots of divs containing text, making a customised table. When a user uses ctrl and clicks on multiple rows sometimes the table content gets highlighted too. Then this causes a problem when I wish to scroll across the overflow of the table.

Comment: Just use the example for the entry body of the webpage

Comment: Is seem that, this question looks like this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS:

```
.unselectable {
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Note that it won't work on all browsers (I believe IE will have problem with that).

Comment: For IE, look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955277/unselectable-text-cross-browser-solution

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to solve this problem:

```
body {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Webkit */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 */
    /* Currently not supported in Opera but will be soon */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```